# I have a problem for running app on device

Tags: build

Question:

I am getting an error message that reads "Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable" when trying to execute my program on Android Studio. What can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Consider including the applicable code that generated the execution failure message. Also consider adding more diagnostic output displays pertaining to this failure condition.